# Could not set the value of environment variable 'CHANGE_TITLE'

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline

I have this error when I want build a Pull Request Bitbucket with Jenkins.

`Could not set the value of environment variable 'CHANGE_TITLE': could not convert string to current locale`

I don't know why ?

When I restart manually, it's work.

Can you help me ?